# Dynamic sitemap with php

Tags: php, sitemap

How to make sitemap index with php, i need to generate dinamicly sitemap index, i have number of post but have no idea from where to start.

Output should be something like this

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
         <loc>https://www.example.com/sitemap.php?from=50000</loc>
        <lastmod>2018-10-03</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
         <loc>https://www.example.com/sitemap.php?from=10000</loc>
        <lastmod>2018-10-03</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
..........
</sitemapindex>
```

Sitemap will be limited to 50.000 post so `https://www.example.com/sitemap.php?from=50000` will back result from 50.000 up to 100.000, but anyway need just found solution to generate index for site map if i know number of post, and post limit per sitemap is 50000.

Comment: what have you tried so far? this platform is not a free source code provider. do some effort. SOME SUGGESTION: you should used for loop like `for($i=50000; $i<=100000; $ i++)` and concatenate `$i` with url like `sitemap.php?from=$i`. the other way: get post id's from database with last modified date and used foreach loop

Comment: I have try example for($i=0; $i<=1000; $i+=100) and this back me 10 sitemaps link, but what if i have number of post 1010? so for($i=0; $i<=1010; $i+=100) it's back me again 10 link but should be 11,Edit: Actually this is working fine, my mistake

Comment: add your code in the above question with desired output